# Is there any way to dynamically load images from url using Vue?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm using require.context to load the correct image using Vue.js. I'm getting errors from the Unit testing since require.context is not supported. But ... I started thinking that maybe ... the best way to do this import isn't the require.context. Do you guys have any clue what should be the way to import dynamically those images?

```
 const images = require.context('./img/', false, /\.png$/);
 const imageTitleFormated= imageTitle.replace(/\s/g, '');
 return images(`./${imageTitleFormated}.png`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the best way to do it. Webpack would do with relative assets anyways imports. So I didn't need the test. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-

```
getImage() {
  const imageTitleFormated = require(`./img/${image}.png`);
  return imageTitleFormated;
},
```